# How to get correct result of math.ceil

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am implementing excel roundup function using python 3.6 and math.ceil returns the weird results.

`math.ceil(0.56 * 100)` returns 57 while `math.ceil(56)` and `math.ceil(56.0)` return 56.

What should I do to get the correct result for `math.ceil(a * b)`?

Comment: you should check [is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Thanks @Tortar. I checked it and want to get correct result in python.

Comment: as Tortar pointed out, `0.56 * 100 != 56`, it expands to `56.00000000000001` which is your issue. So either only take the first x decimal points, or try something else

Answer (score 0):

I think `math.ceil(round(0.56 * 100, 2))` solves the issue.

Any better method would be appreciated.